# Passing in a function to another function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

Is it better practice to pass in a function to another function that uses it to reduce the scope look up. I am getting quite confused about this stuff.

Without passing it in;

```
function loadSuccess(a, b, c) {

};

function image(url, name, info) {

   var asset = new Image();
   asset.addEventListener("load", function(name, info) {
       return function() {
           loadSuccess(this, name, info);
       };
   }(name, info), false);
   asset.src = url;
};

image(a, b, c);
```

And passing it in;

```
function loadSuccess(a, b, c) {

};

function image(url, name, info, loadSuccess) {

   var asset = new Image();
   asset.addEventListener("load", function(name, info, func) {
       return function() {
           func(this, name, info);
       };
   }(name, info, loadSuccess), false);
   asset.src = url;
};

image(a, b, c, loadSuccess);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance benefit is probably neglegible, but passing the callback makes your function more flexible, allowing you to pass a different callback in an different situation, if needed.

However, I see a problem in your code: tt makes no sense to return anything from an asynchronous callback. It's not your `image` function that will be returning it, but the inner anonymous function you passed to `addEventListener`.

Considering those problems, I'd change the code as follows:

```
function loadSuccess(a, b, c) {

};

function image(url, name, info, func) {
   var asset = new Image();
   asset.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
       func(this, name, info);
   }, false);
   asset.src = url;
};

image(a, b, c, loadSuccess);
```

I also removed the immediately invoked function you had, as I don't see any good reason to use it there.

Comment: `function(...){...}(...)` should be wrapped in parentheses, so that the developers know it's an IIFE rather than a callback.

Comment: I didn't even notice the IIFE (which makes my previous revision wrong). Fixed both now.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had an anonymous return function in there because I was rewriting the code, it previously was in one function call in a for loop, so I had to maintain a closure so that name, and info were kept in there for each loop iteration, thanks for spotting it though as I didn't!

Comment: @user2251919 I also had the wrong parameter name in the function image, just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Both works fine but I think it is good practice to send a callback function as an argument.

Comment: Cool, I knew both were ok, but I like to code in the standard way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first option is to use when the image function always  needs call this loadSucces function.

The second option is to use when you need to choose which callback function you want to execute.

There is also third option in which the fourth parameter is optionnal :

```
function image(url, name, info, loadSuccessParameter) {
    loadSuccessParameter= loadSuccessParameter || loadSuccess;
    [...]

}
```

So you can call this way : image(a, b, c) or this way : image(a, b, c, otherLoadSuccess);

I hope it helps.